# fo:instream-foreign-object does not show the image properly

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I use the below code to show a PNG image in PDF. I use `<fo:instream-foreign-object>` because `<fo:external-graphic>` does not fulfil my requirement to show a image. Refer to issue [external graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564802/area-attribute-in-xsl-fo-external-graphic-with-coordinates)

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object width="50%" content-width="scale-to-fit">
   <svg> 
       <image height="439px" width="1037px" xlink:href="test.png"/>
   </svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

With the above use, I am not able to get the picture in the document. The image is not properly placed in the page and the text in the next paragraph is overlay on top of it.
Please suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: The namespace for svg is missing (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`).

Comment: @potame I have added the namespace for svg in the start of the template.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your current output?

Comment: @TonyGraham. No I cannot do that due to security issues :( . The text from the next paragraph is over the image

Answer (score 0):

With what you show, AH Formatter will use the whole page for the `fo:block` containing the image and put the next paragraph on the next page.

Adding `width`, `height`, and `viewbox` attributes to the `svg` element lets AH Formatter, at least, size the image properly:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object width="50%" content-width="scale-to-fit">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1037" height="439"
        viewBox="0 0 1037 439">
        <image height="439px" width="1037px" xlink:href="test.png"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
    </svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

It may be enough to let FOP use the correct height for the image.